REINFORCE algo don't learn
Im doing the reinforce algo to solve gym env, I try it for discrete action space and everything seems good. But when I tried it on continious action space my algo don't learn. The thing that i dont understand that there is only one function (and one network) that differ for discrete and continious action space.
 def choose_action_softmax(self,state):
        probabilities = F.softmax(self.NN_actor(state),dim=0)
        a = T.multinomial(probabilities, num_samples = 1,replacement=True).squeeze()
        self.log_prob.append( T.log(probabilities[a]))
        
        return a.detach().numpy()

    def choose_action_normal(self,state):
        distrib_parameters = self.NN_actor(state)
        mu = distrib_parameters[::2]
        sigma = F.softplus(distrib_parameters[1::2])+1e-6

        normal=T.distributions.Normal(mu,sigma)
        a = 2*T.tanh(normal.sample()) #the * 2 is only for my test because my action space is [-2,2]
        log_prob = T.sum(normal.log_prob(a))
        self.log_prob.append(log_prob)     

        return a.detach().numpy()

Top: discrete action space, Bottom: continious action space
I tried various learning rate without sucess.
I really think the problem come from my choose_action_normal because my class work for discrete action space.
Ty for reading :)
Here the full code of the full class if you want to look:
class PolicyGradient:
    def __init__(self, env,lr=0.001):
        
        self.env = env
        self.gamma = 1
            
        state_dims = np.prod(env.observation_space.shape)
        # action space class verif
        action_class = env.action_space
        self.policy_used = self.check_action_space(action_class)

        if self.policy_used == "Softmax":
            self.NN_actor = Neural_Network(lr,input_dims=state_dims,output_dims = action_class.n)
        else:
            self.NN_actor = Neural_Network(lr, input_dims = state_dims,output_dims = action_class.shape[0] * 2 ) # *2 for each action we have mean and variance

        self.ep_reward_history=[]
        self.log_prob = []
        
        return

    
    def choose_action(self,state):

        if self.policy_used == 'Softmax':
            a = self.choose_action_softmax(state)
        else:
            a = self.choose_action_normal(state)

        return a
        
    def choose_action_softmax(self,state):
        probabilities = F.softmax(self.NN_actor(state),dim=0)
        a = T.multinomial(probabilities, num_samples = 1,replacement=True).squeeze()
        self.log_prob.append( T.log(probabilities[a]))
        
        return a.detach().numpy()
    def choose_action_normal(self,state):
        distrib_parameters = self.NN_actor(state)
        mu = distrib_parameters[::2]
        sigma = F.softplus(distrib_parameters[1::2])+1e-6

        normal=T.distributions.Normal(mu,sigma)
        a = 2*T.tanh(normal.sample()) #the * 2 is only for my test because my action space is [-2,2]
        log_prob = T.sum(normal.log_prob(a))
        self.log_prob.append(log_prob)     

        return a.detach().numpy()
              
            
    def check_action_space(self,action_class):
        if isinstance(action_class,gym.spaces.Discrete):
            policy = "Softmax"
        elif isinstance(action_class,gym.spaces.Box):
            policy = "Normal"
        else:
            print("Unknow action_space")
            sys.exit()
        return policy
        
    def discounted_reward(self,normalize = False):
        reward_history= self.ep_reward_history
        total_reward=[]
        discounted_sum = 0
        for reward in reward_history[::-1]:
            discounted_sum = reward + self.gamma * discounted_sum
            total_reward.insert(0,discounted_sum)
        if normalize is True:
            total_reward=np.array(total_reward)
            total_reward=(total_reward-np.mean(total_reward))/(np.std(total_reward)+1E-7)
            total_reward=list(total_reward)


        return total_reward
            
        
    def learn(self):
        G = T.tensor( self.discounted_reward(normalize = True) )
        log_prob = T.stack( self.log_prob).reshape(-1) 
        loss = T.mean(-log_prob * G)
        #gradient step
        self.NN_actor.optimiser.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.NN_actor.optimiser.step()

        self.log_prob=[]
        self.ep_reward_history=[]
                
        
    def train(self,nb_episode,score_wanted = 2**32):
        #list to track reward and to do a moving average of it
        reward_history=[]
        moving_average=[]
        for ep in tqdm(range(nb_episode)):
            observation=self.env.reset()[0]
            done=False
            score=0        
            while not done:
    
                
                action= self.choose_action(observation)
                observation_, reward, terminated, truncated, info = self.env.step(action)
                done = terminated or truncated
                score += reward
                
                self.ep_reward_history.append(reward)                      
                observation = observation_            

            
            self.learn()
            reward_history.append(score)
            #REWARD PLOT
            window_average=1000
            
            if( len(reward_history) >= window_average ):
                moving_average.append( np.mean(reward_history[-window_average:] ))
                if moving_average[-1] >= score_wanted: 
                    print(moving_average[-1])
                    print("finish")
                    break

            if ((ep+1) % (nb_episode//20) ) == 0 :
                clear_output(wait=True)
                x=np.arange(window_average,len(moving_average)+window_average)
                plt.plot(x,moving_average)
                plt.show()     
            #finish
        return

